# Get duplicate items in a list and display answer in a list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to find duplicate (non unique) items in a list.
For example from
    `duplicate([a,b,c,a,b,r,d,c], R).`
I need to get `[a,b,c]`.

I've written so far prolog program that finds duplicate elements in a list.

However, I get the answer as single elements.

```
R = a
R = b
R = c
```

And I have to get them in a list as `[a,b,c]`

```
duplicate([First|Rest], Element) :-
duplicate_first(Rest, First, Element).

duplicate_first([Head|Rest], X, X) :-
     duplicate_second(Rest, Head, X).
duplicate_first([Head|Rest], _, X) :-
     duplicate_first(Rest, Head, X).

duplicate_second(_, X, X).
    duplicate_second([Head|Rest], _, X) :-
    duplicate_second(Rest, Head, X).
```

P.S. I don't want to use any swi-prolog build in functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it a bit of a straightjacket to ignore the standard library. But you can fulfill the requirement by implementing the two predicates you need, which are `member/2` and `delete/3`, yourself:

```
my_member(X, [X|_]).
my_member(X, [_|Xs]) :- my_member(X, Xs).
```

This is probably the most straightforward way to implement `member/2`, although it isn't exactly the same as in the SWI library.

```
my_delete([], _, []).
my_delete([X|Xs], X, Ys) :- my_delete(Xs, X, Ys).
my_delete([Y|Xs], X, [Y|Ys]) :- X \= Y, my_delete(Xs, X, Ys).
```

I just sort of took a crack at this and it seems to be OK. A better implementation would probably use something like `X = Y -> ...` but that can lead to issues with backtracking so I am using this variation which probably has other problems.

Now that you have the preliminaries, the actual implementation is not that hard. First your base case. There are no duplicates in the empty list.

```
duplicates([], []).
```

Now you have two inductive cases. One, in which the head of the list occurs inside the tail of the list. When that happens you add it to the result and remove it from the tail (or you'll get duplicates in your list of duplicates).

```
duplicates([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
    my_member(X, Xs),
    my_delete(Xs, X, XsWithoutX),
    duplicates(XsWithoutX, Ys).
```

Your other case is when the head element does not appear in the tail, so you can simply recur and find the rest of the duplicates:

```
duplicates([X|Xs], Ys) :-
    \+ my_member(X, Xs),
    duplicates(Xs, Ys).
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. That was what I was looking for.

Comment: @Adomas202 glad to help, hope you enjoy using Prolog!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little out of practice so the following code can be simplified but... given a filter function (that remove the `Val` correspondences from a list and return `[Val]` if correspondence is found or empty list otherwise)

```
filter(_, [], [], []).

filter(Val, [Val | Rest], [Val], LR) :-
   filter(Val, Rest, _, LR).

filter(Val1, [Val2 | Rest], LO, [Val2 | LR]) :-
   Val1 \= Val2,
   filter(Val1, Rest, LO, LR).
```

and given a sort of optional adder in front of a list

```
addOptional([], L, L).

addOptional([O], L, [O | L]).
```

I suppose you can write `duplicate/2` as follows

```
duplicate([], []).

duplicate([First | Rest], Result) :-
   filter(First, Rest, Opt, Filtered),
   duplicate(Filtered, Res2),
   addOptional(Opt, Res2, Result).
```